# Display Suite module is not displaying field labels

Tags: display-suite

I am using the [Display Suite](https://drupal.org/project/ds) module (version 7.x-1.9) and Drupal 7.37.

I selected above or inline in the Label column for all the fields, but I don't see the labels on my page for any fields.

I also don't see the display suite tab when I try to edit the page. If I want to change the layout, I have to go to *admin > module > ds > configure* to change the layout.

Can anyone help me workout what's happening?

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The page you see is from the "**Default**" Manage Display. Make sure you use this instead of others. The Display Suite layout is based on per content type, not per node. To change the Default display, you should go to "***Structure > Content types > Your content type > Manage display***" or "***Strurture > Display Suite > Manage display(your content type)***".

**=== Update: June 25, 2015 at 8:37am - screenshot for @Kaimei Wang ===**
[image]

Comment: @Kaimei Wang Also, there a very useful documentation from here https://www.drupal.org/node/1857540. Hope this help

Comment: Structure > content types > content > manage display: > I have 2 pages layout stack > All the fields display in the correct regions. I expected the labels to be displayed but I don’t see the labels. Please see the above image.

Comment: @Kaimei Wang make sure that is "Default" Manage Display

Comment: When I click the Manage Display tab, I do not see any default option. I have added one more image which shows the bottom of the manage display page. How do I make sure it is "Default" manage display?

Comment: @Kaimei Wang I just updated the post with screenshot. It show where the "Default" setting.

Comment: I just want to let you know that I have used display suite module several times and I did see the "Default" option. Please see the image above which does not show the "Default" option. This is a new content type that I created. However, I do see the "Default" option for Basic page but not for the content type that I added.

Comment: @Kaimei Wang Actually the screenshot you have is showing the "Default" display, because you have disable all other view modes. To enable other view mode, simply use the "Custom display settings" on the bottom. However, it's possible is your theme causing this issue. Try to use some "Developer Tools" from your browser and check the label.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I did enable "teaser" view mode. After that, I saw "Default" and "Teaser" option on the top of the "manage display" tab. I tried in both views mode and I don't see the labels. I will use some "Developer Tools" and see I can find an answer. Again, I have used this module in another site and I did not have this issue.

Comment: @Kaimei Wang try to use a default theme from Drupal. If the label show up, that mean is your theme causing that.